# How to callback `this` within ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I want to use `this` from an outer function within an ajax success function. I tried to apply [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) but somehow I can't bring it to work.

```
// Submit vote on submit
$('.vote-choice-div').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // bind the clicked object
    this.submit_vote.bind(this);    // so I have to bind the element to use it in the ajax function?

    // fire ajax
    submit_vote(this.id, this);

});
```

```
// AJAX for posting
function submit_vote(vote) {

    $.ajax({
            url : "submit-vote/",
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}, 
            type : "POST",
            data : { vote : vote }, 

            success : function(data) {
                 if(data.status === 1){
                    
                     console.log(this)   // can't access the initial clicked element
                 }
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems (and a pointless argument).

1. `submit_vote` is a global, not a property of the element. To access it, you don't use `this`.
2. `bind` **returns** a new function. It doesn't mutate the existing one
3. `submit_vote` only accepts one argument

So:

```
const localSubmitVote = submit_vote.bind(this)
localSubmitVote(this.id);
```

**However**… `bind` is only useful if you are going to store a function so you can pass it around or use it multiple times.

You aren't doing that, you're only calling it once, so use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
submit_vote.call(this, this.id);
```

**However**… `submit_vote` isn't a method. It isn't sensible to design it to use `this` in the first place. So the better approach here is to redesign it to just use the second argument that you were passing before.

```
function submit_vote(vote, element) {
  $.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.status === 1) {
        console.log(element);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

and

```
submit_vote(this.id, this)
```